# Where do I add a click event in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, onclick

Maybe this doesen't even look like a code, but is there any way I can change other components value/state on click?

```
import React from 'react';
import './pokemonList.css';
import {Component} from 'react';
import Pokemon from './Pokemon';    
 class PokemonList extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pokemons : [],
      pokemon : {}
    };
  }
  componentWillMount(){
    fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/').then(res=>res.json())
    .then(response=>{
      this.setState({
        pokemons : response.results,
      });
    });
  }    
handleClick(id) {
  fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}/`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        const pokemon = new Pokemon(data);    
        this.setState({ pokemon: pokemon });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
    console.log("click happened");
}
render(){
    const {pokemons} = this.state; 
    return (
    <div className='pokemonList'> {pokemons.map(pokemon =>(
         <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} className='pokemon- 
         btn' key={pokemon.name}>
          {pokemon.name}
        </button>
        ))}
      </div> 
      )
}}
export default PokemonList;
```

At this point I'm not even sure where does handleClick() has to be, so I put it in my App component aswell. The output is ok, but clicking these buttons doesen't seem to do anything. They are supposed to show detailed pokemon information in  component.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './pokemon-info.css';
const PokemonInfo = ({ pokemon }) => {
  const { name, 
          height, 
          weight, 
          sprite, 
          statsSpeed, 
          statsSpecialDefense, 
          statsSpecialAttack, 
          statsDefense, 
          statsAttack, 
          statsHp 
        } = pokemon;
  return (
    <section className="pokemonInfo">
      <img src={sprite} className='sprite-image' alt="pokemon_sprite"/>
      <div className='data-wrapper'>
        <h3 className="data-char">{pokemon.name}</h3><br />
        <p className = 'data-char'>Height: {height}</p>
        <p className = 'data-char'>Weight: {weight}</p><br />
        <p className = 'data-char'>Stats: </p><br />
        <p className = 'data-char'>Speed: {statsSpeed}</p>
        <p className = 'data-char'>Special defense: {statsSpecialDefense}</p>
        <p className = 'data-char'>Special attack: {statsSpecialAttack}</p>
        <p className = 'data-char'>Defense: {statsDefense}</p>
        <p className = 'data-char'>Attack: {statsAttack}</p>
        <p className = 'data-char'>Hp: {statsHp}</p>
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}
export default PokemonInfo;
```

Here is my App component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import PokemonList from './PokemonList';
import Pokemon from './Pokemon';
import PokemonInfo from './PokemonInfo';
class App extends Component {
 constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      pokemon: {}
    };
    this.handleOnClick = this.handleOnClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleOnClick(id) {
    fetch(`http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}/`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        const pokemon = new Pokemon(data);
        this.setState({ pokemon });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <PokemonList />
        <PokemonInfo pokemon={this.state.pokemon}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

It is obvious I did go wrong somewhere, but where?

Update:

**Pokemon**

```
class Pokemon {
  constructor(data) {
this.id = data.id;
this.name = data.name;
this.height = data.height;
this.weight = data.weight;
this.sprite = data.sprites.front_default;
this.statsSpeed = data.stats[0].stats.base_stat;
this.statsSpecialDefense = data.stats[1].stats.base_stat;
this.statsSpecialAttack = data.stats[2].stats.base_stat;
this.statsDefense = data.stats[3].stats.base_stat;
this.statsAttack = data.stats[4].stats.base_stat;
this.statsHp = data.stats[5].stats.base_stat;
  }
}
export default Pokemon;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `App` component should keep the state and pass updater functions as props to children components:

**PokemonList**

```
import React from "react";
import "./pokemonList.css";
import { Component } from "react";
import Pokemon from "./Pokemon";
class PokemonList extends Component {    
  render() {
    const { pokemons } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="pokemonList">
        {pokemons.map(pokemon => (
          <button
            onClick={() => this.props.handleClick(pokemon.id)} // id or whatever prop that is required for request
            className="pokemon-btn"
            key={pokemon.name}
          >
            {pokemon.name}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**PokemonInfo** - no change here.

**APP**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import PokemonList from "./PokemonList";
import Pokemon from "./Pokemon";
import PokemonInfo from "./PokemonInfo";
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      pokemon: {},
      pokemons: [],
    };
    this.handleOnClick = this.handleOnClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          pokemons: response.results
        });
      });
  }

  handleOnClick(id) {
    fetch(`http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}/`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        const pokemon = new Pokemon(data);
        this.setState({ pokemon });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <PokemonList pokemons={this.state.pokemons} handleClick={this.handleOnClick} />
        <PokemonInfo pokemon={this.state.pokemon} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

More on [lifting the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lifting-state-up).

Comment: That's weird, everything seems to be fine now, but that click does not change PokemonInfo component. The console says: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'front_default' of undefined
    at new Pokemon (Pokemon.js:7)
    at App.js:30" Maybe something could be wrong with my Pokemon component

Comment: Could it be a problem that this [link](https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/) has JSON string with only 2 properties: url and name? But I need to update my PokemonInfo component from the info given at for example from [link](https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/3/)

Comment: I will check that later

Comment: @SergeyShpironok `http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}/` returns (like you wrote) only `name` and `url` that's why `Pokemon` constructor fails as there is no `sprites` property to derive `front_default` from.

Comment: as far as I understand it I need to `fetch` the data from here `fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/")` somehow using `url` property? Is it even possible t fetch from fetched data?

Comment: That's a little bit out of the scope of this question. You need to somehow get full data to create Pokemon object. You can do it with Promises.